# Нужна помощь в устранении неверных подсчетов

Tags: python, python-3.x

Мой Python код работает, но работает некорректно. Я выяснил, в каком месте, сейчас попытаюсь все изложить.
Код:

```
def score(arr):
    line = 0
    total = 0
    level = 0
    
    for i in arr:
        line += i
    
        if line > 10:
            level += 1
            line = 0 
        
        if i == 0:
            total += 0
            print(total)
        
        elif i == 1:
            total += (40 * (level + 1))
        
            print(total)
        
        elif i == 2:
            total += (100 * (level + 1))
        
            print(total)
        
        elif i == 3:
            total += (300 * (level + 1))
        
            print(total)
        
        elif i == 4:
            total += (1200 * (level + 1))
        
            print(total)
```

Задача этого кода: подсчет очков. На вход массив с любым кол-вом элементов 0~4. Затем идет 'пробежка' по всем элементам массива, это все можно понять в коде. Вся проблема в переменных `line` и `level`. Я покажу. Есть массив:

```
[2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 3, 0, 4]
```

Если применить функцию к этому массиву, то результатом должно будет быть число 1780, но у меня вышло число 2980. Вот мой вывод:

```
100
140
140
240
280
580
580
2980
```

Как мы видим, все, что после цифры 4 имеет `level` равный 1, следовательно, цифра 4 приносит 2400 очков, но мне надо, чтобы цифра 4 приносила по прежнему 1200 очков, потому что сумма всех элементов этого массива (`[2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 3, 0, 4]`) БЕЗ последней цифры 4 равна 9, а согласно условию переменная `level` повышается на 1 ТОЛЬКО когда `line` больше 10, а на данный момент `line` равна 9, следовательно кол-во очков, которые приносит цифра 4 умножается на 1, а не на 2:

```
elif i == 4:
    total += (1200 * (level + 1)) # 1200 * 1 (Не на 2, т.к. line = 9, а уровень повышается только тогда, когда line > 10, следовательно, на данный момент level = 0)
```

Значение переменной `line` и `level` повышается сразу же, как только прибавляется цифра 4, но мне надо, чтобы как только прибавилась цифра 4, значение `level` по прежнему оставалось 0.

Мне нужна Ваша помощь, может, порекомендуете полезные модули для решения этой проблемы, а если Вы собрались написать решение моей проблемы, то пожалуйста, пишите с объяснением. Спасибо!

Если Вы что-то не поняли, то напишите, пожалуйста. Я объяснил, как смог...

Comment: для начала дайте, пожалуйста, вопросу осмысленный заголовок. [edit]

Answer (score 1):

*сумма всех элементов этого массива ([2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 3, 0, 4]) БЕЗ последней цифры 4 равна 9, а согласно условию переменная level повышается на 1 ТОЛЬКО когда line больше 10, а на данный момент line равна 9,*

Когда мы проходим по последнему элементу - четверке:

```
for i in arr:
        line += i      // 9 += 4 и вот здесь line уже будет равен 13
    
        if line > 10:  // соотв. этот if выполнится и level будет равен 1
            level += 1
            line = 0
```

Как решение, складывайте цифры в конце цикла, а не в самом начале